# How do you do a for loop as a while condition?

Tags: c++, vector

I have to get a result from a loop through a vector as a condition, and then perform a task on that result.

```
do{result}
```

my data is continuous inbound json data stripped of it's json properties in groups of 7.
I need to validate to item[2] and then send item[3] to a different vector.

my condition is

```
(for(int b = 2; b < buydat.size(); b+=7);
buydat[b] == "Buy")
```

my action is

```
do{
    pricedat.push_back(buydat[3]);
}
```

my result can be displayed as

```
for(int d = 0; d < pricedat.size(); ++d){
    cout << pricedat[d] << " " << endl;
}
```

my code:

```
vector<std::string> buydat;
vector<std::string> pricedat;
for(int b = 2; b < buydat.size(); b+=7){
    do{
        pricedat.push_back(buydat[3]);
    }
    while(
        //(int b = 2; b < buydat.size(); b+=7;)
        buydat[b] == "Buy"
    );
}
```

my error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted
```

How do I do a for loop result as a condition?
loop 7 times through data -> validate to item[2]  -> send item[3] in that series to a vector.

Comment: Your condition does not terminate. `buydat[b]` is not modified in the body of the `do`-`while` loop.

Comment: Currently you have two nested loops; as soon as `buydat[b] == "Buy"` is true, the inner loop never exits and so you run out of memory for your vector.  I'm having trouble seeing what you meant to do instead, perhaps you meant `if ( buydat[b] == "Buy" ) { pricedat.push_back(buydat[3]); }` ?  In any case it'd be useful to update your post explaining what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: it's supposed to terminate every 7 and then do it again with the next set.

Comment: and do what with every 7?

Comment: capture one of the items in the results of that set   pricedat.push_back(buydat[3]);

Comment: It looks like you just want an if instead of the do {} while();

Comment: if(buydat[b] == "Buy")   yields  ->  error: expected primary-expression before 'if'

Comment: the do{} is the action needed at the time of the result.

Comment: ***the do{} is the action needed at the time of the result.*** Which is what `if ( buydat[b] == "Buy" ) { pricedat.push_back(buydat[3]); }` would do for you.

Comment: It will help if you can post a brief outline, a description, of how you expect your overall logic to work. It's hard to figure out exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik  loop 7 times through data -> validate to item[2] -> send item[3] in that series to a vector.   I edited the question as well.

Comment: @drescherjm using if like that, produces the same record over and over again. it never cycles to the next.

Comment: Your for loop `for(int b = 2; b < buydat.size(); b+=7){` should advance b.

Comment: @drescherjm I could not figure out how to do that. I once used a bool when the data was coming from fgets, but now the operator won't work, because of my vector  https://bpaste.net/show/bb1a67687a26  ->  :54:63: error: no match for 'operator!=' in 'buydat.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::basic_string<char> .....

Comment: Just put the `if ( buydat[b] == "Buy" ) { pricedat.push_back(buydat[3]); }` inside of the for{} and get rid of all of the do{} while() loops. You do not need any bool for that.

Comment: @drescherjm that does not work  https://bpaste.net/show/d621bc98a06d It captures the first item over and over and never cycles to the next item. won't work.

Comment: Well regardless of what the value of b is when `buydat[b] == "Buy"` use insert `buydat[3]` into the vector so it is expected that the value will always be the same. Perhaps you want `buydat[b+3]` instead of `buydat[3]`? I can't tell because I do not know what you are doing and with your current description its hard to follow.

Comment: @drescherjm I definately don't want b+3. Here is the data.  https://bpaste.net/show/1517cb350f44 what I need is all the 'price's following a validation for Buy.

Comment: Then its `buydat[b+1]`. so `if ( buydat[b] == "Buy" ) { pricedat.push_back(buydat[b+1]); }`

Comment: post it as an answer and I will click the button. That works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments the code should be:

```
vector<std::string> buydat;
vector<std::string> pricedat;
for(int b = 2; b < buydat.size(); b+=7){
    if ( buydat[b] == "Buy" ) { 
      pricedat.push_back(buydat[b+1]); 
    }
}
```

Your original code had an infinite loop and also used the wrong index to the buydat array.